# Create a monthly records tables from different scripts 2

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask for some idea support how to achieve to create a table from 5 different MYSQL scripts in PHP. The result of each of them is SUM of data group by months. I do not want to vast time much to scripts because all of them are ok when activates alone.

I will put theoretical query in order to not make my message very long.

**IMPORTANT**: all queries are independent and have own join tables. They have nothing in common. But all of them are numbers which can be grouped by month.

```
<?php
$qry = "SUM(CASH) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());

$qry2 = "SUM(DEBT) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry2) or die(mysql_error());

$qry3 = "SUM(DEBTPAID) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry3) or die(mysql_error());

$qry4 = "SUM(INVOICE) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry4) or die(mysql_error());

$qry5 = "SUM(NVOICEPAYOFF) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry5) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

I want to achieve a TABLE like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>CASH</td>
  <td>DEBT</td>
  <td>DEBTPAID</td>
  <td>INVOICE</td>
  <td>INVOICEPAYOFF</td>
</tr>
<?
echo '<tr>';

echo '<td><label>'. $row['CASH'] .'</label></td>';
echo '<td><label>'. $row2['DEBT'] .'</label></td>';
echo '<td><label>'. $row3['DEBTPAID'] .'</label></td>';
echo '<td><label>'. $row4['INVOICE'] .'</label></td>';
echo '<td><label>'. $row5['INVOICEPAYOFF'] .'</label></td>';
echo '</tr>';

?>
</table>
```

I will appreciete your every idea, solutions or recommendation. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should replace all your `mysql_*` functions. As of `PHP 5.5.0` they are deprecated, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: What is the problem you're having with the current solution?

Comment: I do not know how to put them together.... it seems that I need to put WHILE or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then the queries can't be combined (though that may not be the case we'd need the full queries to see). In that case you can simply do:

```
$row = array();
$qry = "SUM(CASH) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
$row['cash'] = mysql_fetch_field($result);

$qry2 = "SUM(DEBT) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry2) or die(mysql_error());
$row['debt'] = mysql_fetch_field($result);

$qry3 = "SUM(DEBTPAID) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry3) or die(mysql_error());
$row['debtpaid'] = mysql_fetch_field($result);

$qry4 = "SUM(INVOICE) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry4) or die(mysql_error());
$row['invoice'] = mysql_fetch_field($result);

$qry5 = "SUM(INVOICEPAYOFF) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry5) or die(mysql_error());
$row['invoicepayoff'] = mysql_fetch_field($result);
//Add HTML Table here.
foreach($row as $val){
    echo '<td><label>'. $row['CASH'] .'</label></td>';
}
```

You should consider replacing the mysql_ functions. These are now deprecated.